# If I'm going to delete a shared branch, is it OK to rebase?

Tags: git

Say I have two branches - `master` and `feature`. `feature` is pushed to origin and multiple developers are working on. All developers have finished their work, committed it and pushed to the shared branch. I pull all changes into my local checkout of `feature` so it's up to date.

I run `git merge-base master feature` and it gives me `433c4d34e86c3997ffc0ab1b42bb27acce09b2a6`.

I want to make this just one commit, so I run `git rebase -i 433c4d34e86c3997ffc0ab1b42bb27acce09b2a6`. For the first commit I use `reword` and for the rest I use `fixup`. The rebase finished and, as expected, it tells me my branch and `origin/feature` have diverged. **I don't push.**

I `git checkout master` then `git pull` and finally `git rebase master feature`. Finally, I `git checkout master` again then `git merge feature`.

`git status` now tells me:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

At this point, **is it safe to push to origin**? Bearing in mind the feature branch will be deleted and never used again so we're not worried about other devs having their history rewritten from that point of view.

Or am I missing something else here as to why this is bad? Maybe a better way of doing it altogether?

Comment: No history is going to be rewritten if you push that. It’ll add one commit to master. The faster way of doing this is `git merge --squash feature`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two points of confusion here.

First, it sounds like you're concerned about the general advice to never rebase a branch that's been pushed, but you aren't sure if you understand the reason for that advice.

The potential that other developers will have to clean up the state of their copy of the branch is the reason for this guideline; and so a better form of the advice is, if you want to rebase a branch that has been pushed/shared with others, you need the agreement of everyone who has a copy of the branch.

If everyone agrees that they're not doing any more work on `feature`, and that all work done on `feature` has been pushed already, and that they're just going to delete `feature`; then there's no extra work created for anyone by rebasing `feature`, and nobody should have a problem with it.

But even that doesn't matter, because you've described a situation where you are getting ready to push `master`.  The above only applies if you're going to push `feature`... and why would you do that, if it's just a branch you're deleting anyway?  If anything you would locally delete `feature` and push the delete.

So I assume you think there's some internal relationship between a branch and the commits that the branch either can reach now, or could in the past.  There isn't.  The fact that the commit you want to push to `master` came from a rebase of `feature` has no meaning to git.  It's still just a new commit on `master`.

(Which draws attention to another point: you've taken the long way around by doing an interactive rebase.  Maybe the intent was to manipulate the default commit message or something?  But if you want to apply all the changes from `feature` in a single commit to `master`, the easiest thing is

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature
```

which, just like your procedure, can sometimes cause headaches but is usually fine if you're just going to discard `feature` anyway.)

Comment: >*you need the agreement of everyone who has a copy of the branch*. Not exactly... Because git is decentralised, you don't necessarily know all the devs. So, you should know that it will annoy others but you should decide if the rewrite worth it and communicate as much as possible (before and after).

Comment: @Philippe - You're entitled to your opinion; I hope we never work on the same project.